# Problem with std::string::find()

Tags: c++

I'm in trouble using std::string::find(). I read strings from console through the following code:

```
 50   while(command.find(exitString) != 0) {
 51         std::cout << "$ ";
 52         getline(std::cin, command);
 53 
 54         doSwitch(command);
 55     }
```

and then I "switch" on them, through the following function:

```
 59 void Console::doSwitch(std::string command) {
 60     if(command.find(helpString) == 0) {
 61         help();
 62     } else if(command.find(loadString) == 0) {
 63         try {
 64             doLoad(command);
 65         } catch(std::string str) {
 66             std::cout << str << std::endl;
 67         }
 68     } else if(command.find(dumpProcString) == 0) {
 69         try {
 70             doDumpProc(command);
 71         } catch(std::string str) {
 72             std::cout << str << std::endl;
 73         }
 74     } else if(command.find(dumpMemString) == 0) {
 75         doDumpMem();
 76     } else if(command.find(defmemString) == 0) {
 77         try {
 78             doDefmem(command);
 79         } catch(std::string str) {
 80             std::cout << str << std::endl;
 81         } catch(char *str) {
 82             std::cout << str << std::endl;
 83         }
 84     } else if(command.find(resetString) == 0) {
 85         try {
 86             doReset();
 87         } catch(std::string str) {
 88             std::cout << str << std::endl;
 89         }
 90     } else {
 91         std::cout << "Comando inválido." << std::endl;
 92     }
 93 }
```

but sometimes it simply doesn't switch correctly. Any clues?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
I've done some tests and I detected it was falling on the last else-if statement, instead of falling on the last else.
Then I checked my code again and found that the root cause was that I forgot to initialize resetString.
Problem solved!
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Prof. Plum, in the conservatory, with the wrench.

Comment: A few more details -- "sometimes"?  Software is nothing if not deterministic, so when does it work one way and when does it work another?

Comment: Its really helpful if you can provide a test input where it misbehaves.

Comment: Why don't you use a string -> function mapping instead?

Comment: I can't use string -> function mapping 'cause the string I'm searching for may be only the first slice of the entire string entered by the user.

Comment: And the change of behavior seems to be completely random.

Comment: Well, if the behavior is indeed random, then the only rational fix would also have to be random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be expecting that `find` returns zero when it found the string, kind of like the way `strcmp` works.

But that's not how `find` works.  `find` returns the first index of the found string, which might be zero, or might be something else if the string you're looking for is prepended with spaces, other strings, etc.

If `find` *doesn't* find what you're looking for, it returns `string::npos`.  So your if...else block should be checking to find if the strings were found or not found, not checking to see if they were at index zero.  Like this:

```
if(command.find(helpString) != string::npos ) {
          help();
      } else if /// ... etc...
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I really want my string to be contained at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a line and then calling doSwitch() without checking if its exitString. In that case, when the input is exitString, else block at the end of doSwitch() function is executed, causing the program to print "Command Invalido" before exiting the loop.

Is this what you observed?

If its something else, please let us know for what input your code behaves incorrectly and what is the input and output.

Comment: Not really. What I observed is that my if-else sequence seems to ignore the comparisons sometimes. For example, I was using a else-if statement at the end of the sequence and it was not working, then, as a test, I put it in the first places and it worked. But I just couldn't figure out what's happening.